# How to grep lines containing more than 1 word in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a file called **companies.dat** containing lines with several company names. How can I use the  `grep` command to identify and display all the companies with more than 1 word in their name? I'm not searching for any specific word, just a pattern with more than 1 word per line.

Here is the file content:

```
id companyName placeId
1:British Airways:1
2:The New York Times:3
3:Toyota:3
4:BNP Paribas:2
5:EDF:2
6:Tesco:1
7:IBM:1
8:Google:3
9:Castlemaine:5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically have to use `grep` then check for spaces:

```
grep -E '\w\s+\w'
```

Or perhaps:

```
grep '[A-Za-z] [A-Za-z]'
```

This checks for a letter on either side of a space too, but personally I think it a bit less elegant.

Comment: This will fail on company names like `Stuff 4 U`

Comment: `\w` includes alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler with awk:

```
awk 'NF>1' file
```

Comment: What if you have a line like `1:foo:2 3`

Comment: @kvantour OP's example contains `N: one or more words:N`. So if input format, then the pattern needs to be tweaked accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In this example most likely they want you to identify patterns.

If they want you to use grep then you first and foremost access your manual.

You will find that there is -E mode you can use.

In your file, all words are separated by a space like a *pattern*

My solution is:

```
grep -E ' ' /the literal path of the file/companies.dat
```

Comment: I realized that this can bring as well the first line of 
"id companyName  placeId"
thus you might bring more to your pattern

grep -E '^[0-9].*  ' /the literal path of the file/companies.dat

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
grep -o '[a-ZA-Z]*[[:blank:]]\+[a-ZA-Z[:blank:]]*' companies.dat
```

Output:

```
id companyName placeId
British Airways
The New York Times
BNP Paribas
```

If you want to omit the first line (`id companyName placeId`), then:

```
tail -n +2 companies.dat |grep -o '[a-ZA-Z]*[[:blank:]]\+[a-ZA-Z[:blank:]]*'
```

Output:

```
British Airways
The New York Times
BNP Paribas
```

If you want all the other info too, then just omit the `-o` flag from the grep command:

```
tail -n +2 companies.dat |grep '[a-ZA-Z]*[[:blank:]]\+[a-ZA-Z[:blank:]]*'
```

Output:

```
1:British Airways:1
2:The New York Times:3
4:BNP Paribas:2
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust way would be

```
awk -F: '($2 ~ /[^ ] [^ ]/)' file
```

It checks for a space sandwiched between two non-space characters in the second field.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler with awk:

awk 'NF>=1' file

according to your requirement of word count, you can change the value.